# Proof the non-existence of integer solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Use proof by contradiction to prove that :
>   The equation $$3x+18y = 1$$

*My attempt*

Let the equation have at least one integer solution $$x+ 6y = \frac{1}{3}$$
Since $x,y $ are integers, then $x +6y$ is also integer which contradicts the right hand side, so the equation has no integer solution.

Is this solution correct ?

Comment: It is all right, in particular for a precalculus algebra level.

Comment: There is no section related to this topic @DonAntonio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Here is another method: assume $x$ and $y$ are integers, and write the equation as $3(x+6y) = 1$. The left-hand side is a multiple of $3$, while the right-hand side is not. This leads to the same conclusion as before.